# When upload to media it says an error occurred but the file is uploaded

Tags: uploads, user-roles

I created a new user role and I set him a permission to upload to media, when the user finishes to upload he gets an error:

> an error occurred in the upload. please try again later

But the file is uploaded, and when you exit and renter the media you can see the image.

I checked `async-upload.php` request and I saw the response is:

```
<style type="text/css">
.page-title-action { display:none !important; }
</style>{"success":true,"data":{"id":501,"title":"1","filename":"1.jpg","url":"XX\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/04\/1.jpg","link":"XX\/property\/%d7%a8%d7%90%d7%a9%d7%95%d7%9f-%d7%9c%d7%a6%d7%99%d7%95%d7%9f\/attachment\/1\/","alt":"","author":"2","description":"","caption":"","name":"1","status":"inherit","uploadedTo":103,"date":1527687248000,"modified":1527687248000,"menuOrder":0,"mime":"image\/jpeg","type":"image","subtype":"jpeg","icon":"XX\/wp-includes\/images\/media\/default.png","dateFormatted":"30 \u05d1\u05de\u05d0\u05d9 2018","nonces":{"update":false,"delete":false,"edit":false},"editLink":false,"meta":false,"authorName":"test","uploadedToLink":"XX\/wp-admin\/post.php?post=103&action=edit&lang=he","uploadedToTitle":"${G} CITY","filesizeInBytes":119003,"filesizeHumanReadable":"116 KB","context":"","height":257,"width":1151,"orientation":"landscape","sizes":{"thumbnail":{"height":150,"width":150,"url":"XX\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/04\/1-150x150.jpg","orientation":"landscape"},"medium":{"height":67,"width":300,"url":"XX\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/04\/1-300x67.jpg","orientation":"landscape"},"large":{"height":229,"width":1024,"url":"XX\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/04\/1-1024x229.jpg","orientation":"landscape"},"full":{"url":"XX\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/04\/1.jpg","height":257,"width":1151,"orientation":"landscape"},"medium_large":{"height":171,"width":768,"url":"XX\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/04\/1-768x171.jpg","orientation":"landscape"},"square-thumbnail":{"height":257,"width":370,"url":"XX\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/04\/1-370x257.jpg","orientation":"landscape"},"team-thumbnail":{"height":257,"width":410,"url":"XX\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/04\/1-410x257.jpg","orientation":"landscape"},"future-property-thumbnail":{"height":220,"width":220,"url":"XX\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/04\/1-220x220.jpg","orientation":"landscape"},"banner-mobile":{"height":230,"width":320,"url":"XX\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/04\/1-320x230.jpg","orientation":"landscape"}},"compat":{"item":"","meta":""}}}
```

It looks like the html that got there is making the system to think the file failed to upload. Buy i have no idea where its coming from ...

This is how i set to role:

```
add_role(
'property_editor',
'מנהל נכס',
array(
    "read" => true,
    "edit_others_posts" => true,
    "upload_files" => true,
)
);

function add_theme_caps() {
    // gets the administrator role
    $property_editor = get_role('property_editor');

    $property_editor->add_cap('read');
    $property_editor->add_cap('edit_others_posts');
    $property_editor->add_cap('upload_files');
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_theme_caps');
```

Thanks ! :)

Comment: hmmm when you say the media, do you mean the media library via the admin area, a custom uploader, the REST API, or the javascript backbone powered media library that pops up in the post screens?

Comment: @TomJNowell i mean the media library via the admin area. through an acf field btw.